# How the US verifies person's citizeship given that US passports are optional?

Tags: usa

Consider a person in the US which has no papers but claiming he has a US citizenship. How the authorities verify that he is indeed a citizen rather than an illegal immigrant, given that neither passport nor residency registration is mandatory?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about national citizenship law (how to prove citizenship).

Comment: While its an interesting answer, the asker's intention seems nothing related to travel

Comment: Perhaps there are "special" travel requirements involved in their [vocation](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/3098104.stm).

Comment: @CGCampbell: I'm pretty sure that's just to speed up the common case and there are fallback methods.

Comment: Consider a person in *any* country trying to obtain a passport. How does that person prove he or she is eligible for one? In any case, for most Americans, the only time your citizenship would be relevant on a semi-regular basis are jury duty and elections. Most people do not want to serve on juries, so that is a non-issue. For elections, as recent as 8 years ago, a majority of states required [no identification whatsoever](http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/voter-id-laws-are-now-in-17-more-states-than-they-were-in-2000/), and the introduction of that requirement is highly controversial.

Comment: @choster what about getting driver's license or taxpayer's number or a job or a bank account?

Comment: @choster in Russia everybody obtains a passport at 14, an adult wanting a passport without having the previous one lost, would be highly suspect. Also one can get the passport only at the place of resident registration, and people are registered in their homes at birth. So one cannot come to an arbitrary police office and ask for a passport. The real identity holder will instantly discover the issue because he will come for the passport at the same time (as he reached 14) and will be told that somebody already got it.

Comment: @choster If somebody forges a passport loss and a new passport issued to a wrong person, the older passport becomes obsolete, so it becomes instantly known to the true owner that somebody impersonates him (in Russia passport is needed even if u want to buy an intercity bus ticket or exchange currency, and always checked against database). And to get a new passport after loss, you would need to have the same look and signature as the true owner, because his photos and signature are already in the database.

Comment: @Anixx There is no official national ID in the U.S., however by combining other forms of ID (mostly issued at the state level or corporate) such as drivers license, credit cards, birth certificate and so on, individuals can be uniquely identified. For taxation and related financial information, the Social Security Number is a defacto Federal identification.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany and how u get that number or credit card without a passport?

Comment: @Anixx Passports are not required to get a credit card, a SSN or anything else except to get back in the U.S.A. (there are exceptions even to that requirement). Fewer than 50% of Americans have a passport. Normally drivers license is the photo ID for in-country.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany so how u get a driver's license or SSN? Do they believe your words? Or do u use a birth certificate?

Comment: @Anixx "Trust is just a name on a bank", no, you must provide documents. The exact requirements are going to vary state-by-state, but here are the Illinois requirements for a [drivers license](https://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/publications/pdf_publications/dsd_x173.pdf). SSN requires [these](http://www.ssa.gov/ssnumber/ss5doc.htm) documents.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Thanks! The Illinois link does not work though.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany and... it seems they will not give u an SSN if u dont have a passport or driving license or any other ID. More surprising is that the passport is not sufficient alone...

Comment: What do you mean by "verify"? The burden of proof falls on the side initiating the action for which citizenship is an issue. For example, if you apply for a passport or other benefit, then you initiated the action, and the burden is on you to provide satisfactory documents. You may be a citizen, but if you can't provide the proof, then too bad, you don't get the benefit.

Comment: On the other hand, if the government seeks to deport you, they are initiating the action, so the burden of proof is initially on them. They must first prove that you were not born in the U.S., and then the burden of proof shifts to you, to prove that you are nevertheless a citizen (by birth abroad to U.S. citizen parents, or by naturalization or derivative citizenship). It may be the case that you don't have documents to prove you are a citizen, yet the government can't deport you because they cannot prove you were not born abroad.

Comment: @user102008 Interesting reasoning! In Russia (and possibly in other countries with civil law) this logic definitely would not work. In Russia you are either a citizen or not a citizen legally. In the first case you have all citizen's right and cannot be denied any, in the later case you do not have citizen's rights. There cannot be any intermediate "status quo".

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately birth records, represented by a birth certificate.

This is just an official document that proves a certain person is a US citizen. The question conflates this with how a person proves that they are who they claim they are.

For that purpose, there are all kinds of databases (which do include photos) kept by various agencies. If you try using someone else's identity (aka identiy theft), you'll eventually run into a situation where someone notices that the photos don't match. Or, if you look similar enough, someone will notice that two people are using the same identity. You can't use a dead person's identity either because deaths are also recorded in these databases.

Comment: They have no photo. Suppose one claims he is John Doe born in 1975 in certain place (which birth is recorded).

Comment: @Anixx: see updated answer.

Comment: @Anixx This is really the correct answer. Don't confuse proof of identity with proof of citizenship. In the US, the primary proof of citizenship is a birth certificate (for citizens born here). If I am required to prove my citizenship, I give my birth cert and I would be good to go. If they were to then claim I was not that person, I would need to prove my identity, a separate event, with a photo id.

Answer (score 3):

For Americans born in the US, a birth certificate (typically issued by the U.S. State where the person was born, or the State Department if the person was born abroad), possibly **certified**, *usually* suffices (see below for limitations when applying for a passport). For others, certificate of Citizenship or Naturalization Certificate (or a U.S. passport). Reference [here](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/A4en.pdf).

There are also secondary proofs possible. See [here](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/information/secondary-evidence.html). Also, the documents required to prove citizenship for a [U.S. passport application](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/212239.pdf) may be of interest.

Comment: Birth certificate does not have a photo. What if a person uses another person's birth certificate or claims he lost his own and pretend to be certain person whose birth has been recorded?

Comment: @Anixx A photo of a baby would not be very useful anyway! They all look like Winston Churchill. You might be asked to present photo ID (that does not necessarily require citizenship, such as a drivers license) **plus** a birth certificate. Many years ago it was possible to apply for a birth certificate of a dead person (say one that died as a child) and get false ID issued by the legitimate authorities (eg. as in the novel _Day of the Jackal_) but that's not possible with modern record keeping.